# Turn Popups On/Off in ArcGIS Online Webmap via Javascript API Web Application

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, popup, arcgis-online

I am writing my first ArcGIS Javascript API web map application and consuming a web map authored in ArcGIS Online.  The ArcGIS Online web map apparently does most of the work for me in terms of symbology, editing templates, and even popups.

For my application, I am trying to allow the user to edit features, but not all the time.  I am able to toggle the editor on and off with the click of a button.  The problem is that I have not been able to toggle the default popups on and off so that the user can edit attributes.  Even when editing is enabled, the default non-editable popup appears when you click on a feature.  The only way to avoid this is to use the `ignorePopups` option when calling `esri.arcgis.utils.createMap`.  However, this means that when editing is disabled nothing happens when you click on a feature.

Here is my code.  This has all been adapted from several samples provided in the ArcGIS Javascript API documentation.

```
    <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.3/"></script>
    <script>
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.StackContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
        dojo.require("esri.dijit.editing.Editor-all");
        dojo.require("esri.map");
        dojo.require("esri.IdentityManager");
        dojo.require("esri.dijit.OverviewMap");
        dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
        dojo.require("esri.dijit.Legend");
        dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");

        var map;
        var geometryService = "http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer";
        var layers;
        var templatePicker;
        var editorWidget;
        // var clickHandle;
        // var clickListener;

        function init() {
            esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/proxy/proxy.ashx";
            //This service is for development and testing purposes only. We recommend that you create your own geometry service for use within your applications.
            esri.config.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

            var urlObject = esri.urlToObject(document.location.href);
            var webmap = "0d6761afcb3c45c8840cdbb589f54fa7";
            var bingMapsKey = "/*Please enter your own Bing Map key*/";
            if (urlObject.query) {
                webmap = urlObject.query.webmap;
                bingMapsKey = urlObject.query.bingMapsKey;
            }

            var mapDeferred = esri.arcgis.utils.createMap(webmap, "map", {
                mapOptions : {
                    slider : true
                },
                bingMapsKey : bingMapsKey,
                ignorePopups : true,
                geometryServiceURL : geometryService
            });

            mapDeferred.then(function(response) {
                map = response.map;
                dojo.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
                // dojo.byId("snippet").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;
                dojo.byId("dataSource").innerHTML = "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=" + webmap + "'>View data details</a>";

                layers = response.itemInfo.itemData.operationalLayers;
                // clickHandle = response.clickEventHandle;
                // clickListener = response.clickEventListener;

                //add the legend
                var layerInfo2 = dojo.map(layers, function(layer, index) {
                    return {
                        layer : layer.layerObject,
                        title : layer.title
                    };
                });

                if (layerInfo2.length > 0) {
                    var legendDijit = new esri.dijit.Legend({
                        map : map,
                        layerInfos : layerInfo2
                    }, "legendDiv");
                    legendDijit.startup();
                }

                var overviewMap = new esri.dijit.OverviewMap({
                    map : map
                }, dojo.byId("overviewDiv"));
                overviewMap.startup();
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("CreateMap failed: ", dojo.toJson(error));
            });

        }

        function initEditor(bool) {
            //initialize the editor
            if (bool == true) {

                // dojo.disconnect(clickHandle);

                dojo.create("div", {id: "templateDiv"}, "rightPane")
                dojo.create("div", {id: "editorDiv"}, "rightPane")

                var layerInfo = [];
                var templateInfo = [];

                dojo.forEach(layers, function(layer) {
                    layerInfo.push({
                        'featureLayer' : layer.layerObject
                    });
                    templateInfo.push(layer.layerObject);
                });

                templatePicker = new esri.dijit.editing.TemplatePicker({
                    featureLayers : templateInfo,
                    grouping : true,
                    rows : 'auto',
                    columns : 'auto'
                }, 'templateDiv');
                templatePicker.startup();
                var settings = {
                    map : map,
                    templatePicker : templatePicker,
                    geometryService : new esri.tasks.GeometryService(geometryService),
                    layerInfos : layerInfo,
                    toolbarVisible : true,
                    showAttributesOnClick : true,
                    enableUndoRedo : true
                };

                var params = {
                    settings : settings
                };

                editorWidget = new esri.dijit.editing.Editor(params, 'editorDiv');
                editorWidget.startup();
            } else {
                if (editorWidget) {
                    editorWidget.destroy();
                    editorWidget = null;
                }
                if (templatePicker) {
                    templatePicker.destroy();
                    templatePicker = null
                }
                // dojo.connect(map, "onClick", clickListener);
            }
        }

        //show map on load
        dojo.addOnLoad(init);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showPane(pane, otherpane) {

            if (dojo.style(dojo.byId(pane), "display") == "none") {
                dojo.style(dojo.byId(pane), "display", "block");
                initEditor(true);
            } else {
                dojo.style(dojo.byId(pane), "display", "none");
                initEditor(false);
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        <div id="header" class="roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
            <div id="title"></div>
            <!-- <div id="snippet"></div> -->
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" onclick="showPane('rightPane', 'centerPane');">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="leftPane" class="roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
                    <div id="legendDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
                    This pane could contain tools or additional content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="centerPane" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" class="roundedCorners" data-dojo-props="region:'center',gutters:'false'">
            <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="shadow" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;">
                <div id="ovWin" class="shadow" style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px; z-Index:998; width:100px;height:100px; ">
                    <div id="overviewDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">
                <div id="dataSource"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightPane" class="roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'" style="">
            <!-- <div id="templateDiv"></div>
            <div id="editorDiv"></div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I realize that I could recreate a custom `InfoWindow` and `AttributeInspector`, but since this is already done automatically by the API, it would be nice if I didn't have to.

I tried to get the `clickEventHandle` and `clickEventListener` from the response given by `mapDeffered.then()` and then `connect` and `disconnect` when the editor is disabled and enabled, but the default popups remained even after I called `dojo.disconnect(clickEventHandle)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think you almost have it. It may be that you need to reset the handle on connect...

```
clickHandle = dojo.connect(map, "onClick", clickListener);
```

The following is working for me...

```
var agolPopupClickHandle,
    agolPopupclickEventListener;

    //get the response
    .then {
        agolPopupClickHandle = response.clickEventHandle;
        agolPopupclickEventListener = response.clickEventListener;
    }

    //connect editor
    if (agolPopupClickHandle) {
        dojo.disconnect(agolPopupClickHandle);
        agolPopupClickHandle = null;
    }

    //disconnect editor
    if (!agolPopupClickHandle) {
        agolPopupClickHandle = dojo.connect(theMap, "onClick", agolPopupclickEventListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So with further trial and error, I discovered the issue.  I was unaware of how `dojo.disconnect` and `dojo.connect` work.

If I turn off the `ignorePopups` option when calling `esri.arcgis.utils.createMap` I will get the standard popup.  Then, in the `mapDeferred.then` call, I set global variables

```
clickHandle = response.clickEventHandle
clickListener = response.clickEventListener
```

Later in my `initEditor` function, if `bool == true` then I disconnect `clickHandle`

```
dojo.disconnect(clickHandle)
```

In the `else` clause:

```
dojo.disconnect(clickHandle)  // This will disconnect the original clickHandle if it is still connected
clickHandle = dojo.connect(map, "onClick", clickListener)  // This will reconnect clickListener and return a new clickHandle that can be disconnected next time the editor is enabled
```

The issue was that I had multiple handles connected to the `onClick` event and I was only disconnecting one or the other and not both.

Comment: Lol, I was answering as you posted..

Comment: Can you post the final code?

Answer (score -1):

map.infoWindow.set("popupWindow", false);

Comment: Not enough detail to answer the question.  You should explain why this solves the issue, especially as the OP has accepted one answer and and posted another.